# Terminating the readLine() function when encountered with a whitespace

Tags: kotlin

So, I have started using Kotlin to solve some basic problems at websites like CodeChef and Codeforces where I got caught up on a problem.

The question requires us to input 2 integer variables, say *x* and *y*, followed by *y*-spaced integers, say *m<sub>1</sub>, m<sub>2</sub>, m<sub>3</sub>* and so on till *m<sub>Y</sub>*. But the way it is being input is as shown:

```
4 3
3 2 3
```

And my Kotlin code for input is this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>)
{
    val n = readLine()!!.toInt()
    val m = readLine()!!.toInt()
    var a:Int
    for(i in 1..m) {
         a= readLine()!!.toInt()
        //Some additional manipulation involving all three variables
     }
}
```

Upon submitting, I receive the following message:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4 3"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at ProgramKt.main(program.kt:2)
```

So, in order to make my code my code work, I have to somehow terminate the readLine() method as soon as it encounters a whitespace. Or is there any other method?

Comment: readLine(), as its name implies and as its documentation explains, returns the whole line. So split the line on space, and parse every of its element as an Int.

Comment: So what I could to is perform readLine()!!.split(" ") and store it in a list. And then when required for manipulation, I change the type of list element(s) using toInt() method?

Comment: Why would you change the string to integers every time you get them from the list? Why not construct a list of Ints directly?

Comment: Ah got it I was making a fool out of myself! I had to map those elements to Int type. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was quite simple, after some discussion in the comments. What we have to do is implement the split function and then map each element as an Int.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    val xandy = readLine()!!.split(" ").map{it.toInt()}
    val elems= readLine()!!.split(" ").map{it.toInt()}
    var b=1
    var ans=0
    for(i in 1..xandy[1]){
        //Manipulation stuff
    }
}
```